# upgrading to angular9 issue: Failed to find exported name of node

Tags: angular, npm, angular9, angular-upgrade

After Upgrading to Angular 9 and trying to run my project I got this error :

```
Compiling @angular/common/http : module as esm5
Compiling angular-font-awesome : module as esm5
Compiling angular-font-awesome : module as esm5
Error: Error on worker #5: Error: Failed to find exported name of node (CommonModule = (function () {
    function CommonModule() {
    }
    return CommonModule;
}())) in 'C:/Users/.../node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.es5.js'.
    at Object.findExportedNameOfNode (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\find_export.js:35:19)
    at LogicalProjectStrategy.emit (C:\Users\Ghaida\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\emitter.js:228:38)
    at ReferenceEmitter.emit (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\emitter.js:71:44)
    at Object.toR3Reference (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\util.js:173:31)
    at NgModuleDecoratorHandler._toR3Reference (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\ng_module.js:415:31)
    at C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\ng_module.js:196:72
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at NgModuleDecoratorHandler.analyze (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\ng_module.js:196:38)
```

this is the result of running ng version :

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.0
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.0
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.0
@angular/http                     7.2.16
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.0
@schematics/angular               9.1.0
@schematics/update                0.901.0
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

PS: I runner 'ng update' and got ' we analysed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. '

Comment: Not really answering the question, but it looks like author of this library [stopped maintaining it](https://github.com/baruchvlz/angular-font-awesome#readme) - repository is archived. Consider switching to FA 5 and [it's official Angular library](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome).

Answer (score 5):

**Problem solved** after removing

1. angular-font-awesome from my package.json
2. AngularFontAwesomeModule from app.module.ts

and running npm install

Comment: How is this solution to the problem ?

Comment: Well, according to the error shown above, there was something not working with the AngularFontAwesomeModule.. so the suggested solution solved my problem and the error was gone

Comment: Yup, this worked for me, thanks !  I long for the day that Angular actually presents us with error messages which make sense and hints at what the cause is, rather than us having to run to StackOverflow to decipher the error messages  !!!

Comment: so with is angular version, cant i use angular-font-awesome npm?

Comment: What about font-awesome classes that you have used in the html files? Does that still work or you have to remove those classes also?

Comment: the same happens to me. I just removed this library and it works!

Answer (score 0):

In error it comes when compile the font awesome package. When I show that i remove the package from ngModule and It works.

Answer (score 0):

This library angular-font-awesome is built with Angular v4!! It is not going to be possible to support it in v9. It should be removed from package.json. Here is the [issue on ngcc project](https://github.com/angular/ngcc-validation/issues/105)